# jQuery Datepicker, Check-Out Date is One Day After Check-In Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm setting up a website that has a "Check-In" date and "Check-Out" date date selector. I need the "Check-Out" date to automatically set to the day after the check-in date.

I found a piece of code [here](http://vivekmoyal.in/testing/plus-date.html), but for some reason it does not seem to be working.

I set up a CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Aplao).

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
if (this.id == 'datepicker') {
var dateMin = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 1);
var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 15);
$('#datepicker2').val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(rMax)));
}
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code pen, erase this:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
jQuery( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});
```

Then try again.
But if you want the day after, perhaps you meant `rMin` rather than `rMax` at the end.

Comment: That worked great! However, I would still like the user to be able to select a date in the "Check-Out" date in case the next day is not the day they wish to check-out.

We just need to default to the next day because if no date is selected, an error occurs.

Comment: @JeremyE Add this `$("#datepicker2").datepicker();` after the first line, `$(function () {` Format the datepicker options as you like.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v34xV/)**

THIS is working demo here checkout date is one day after selected date automatically..

```
 $("#CheckInDatePicker").datepicker({     
            defaultDate: "+0",               
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
            minDate: "+0",
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var d = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, dateText);
             d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
                $("#CheckOutDatePicker").val($.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d));

           },

            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#CheckOutDatePicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple using default datepicker plugins of JQuery. Code in jsfiddle contains 2 text box one for checkin and another for checkout.

```
$( "#checkin" ).datepicker({minDate : 0, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
```

[Hit Me !! For code...](https://jsfiddle.net/nb76c2nc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

All I did was put the "datepicker2" function again underneath the solution you provided. Then when I clicked in the "Check-Out" box, it worked and brought up the calendar again with the day after the checkout date default selected in the bright blue. Thanks for this. I was struggling with it too.

```
[<script>
  $(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
if (this.id == 'datepicker') {
var dateMin = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 1);
var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 1);
$('#datepicker2').val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(rMax)));
}
}
});
});
</script>][1]


<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"}

    );

  } );
  </script>
```

THE HTML:

```
<div class="column1">
    <span>CHECK-IN</span>
    <br />
    <input name="DateIn" type="text" id="datepicker"/>
  </div>


   <div class="column2">
   <span>CHECK-OUT</span>
 <br />
    <input name="DateOut" type="text" id="datepicker2"/>
  </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4I5k.png)